# How to identify the calling iframe from parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a document, with some javascript and n number of iFrames with random id's on them.

Within an arbitrary iframe, I call:

```
parent.DoSomething();
```

This works fine, and the code executes, however I have an assumption in my DoSomething() code, that I would like to take out.

I need to know the ID of the iFrame that "called" the `parent.DoSomething()`

Like:

```
<script>
function DoSomething(){
    caller.frame.id // <-- wishful code here
}
</script>
<iframe id=123abc></iframe>
<iframe id=456def></iframe>
...
<iframe id=012jkl></iframe>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe pass frame id as argument to `parent.DoSomething("some_id");`?

Comment: I was really hoping to not parse an argument - the project is quite far along. Changes to the iframe code is tricky - hence the reason for the question, otherwise I would have just parsed the id or an object to the function.